# Connect web server to another application

Tags: c++, python, web, architecture

I'm interested in how I might send requests from a web server using Python to a constantly running C++ program.  Basically users should be able to send "orders" via their browser to the web server.  The web server then needs to forward those orders to a constantly running application written in C++.  Eventually the C++ program should be able to send order results back to the web server who can forward the results to the user's browser if they're still connected.

I've thought about having the web server record pending orders to a database which the C++ program polls for changes.  That doesn't seem very efficient though.  I believe it will have issues with to many users.  Is there some method/technology that is typically used for this type of situation?

Comment: Some form of persistence--whether log files or a database--should be present so you can debug, recover, and analyze data moving through the system.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options;

### 1. API

This is more the traditional option, you have some form of API built into your website, and your C++ program contacts the API to receive and update orders. You would probably want to use this if your C++ program isn't hosted on the same server. However you will need to ensure you keep the API secure from outside parties accessing it to fake orders etc.

### 2. Shared file or database

If your application is running on the same server you could have both programs access a database or flat-file.

### 3. Sockets (TCP)

This method is likely overkill, you have your C++ program act as TCP server and your python program connects to it and sends it the orders as they come in. You should be aware that programming this option would be significantly harder to the previous options, however it provides an instant response that the others don't.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to implement BaseHttpServer on python, use pipe to communicate with c++ process and proxy_pass clients`s requests via web server.